# Txt to JSON split per paragraph

Tags: json, parsing

I have a large collection of documents in text format that I want to put into JSON. Here is my parser that splits the text into a new JSON string after everyline using "/n", I want to change this to cut every paragraph.

```
package main

import (
"bufio"
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io"
"log"
"os"
"strings"
)

func main() {
myBigThing := make(map[string]map[string]string)
f, _ := os.Open("strangecountess.txt")
r := bufio.NewReader(f)
var currentPage map[string]string
pageNum := 0
for {
    line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            log.Println("Error in parsing :", err)
        }
        break
    }
    if currentPage == nil {
        currentPage = make(map[string]string)
        myBigThing[fmt.Sprintf("page%d", pageNum)] = currentPage
        pageNum++
    } else if line == "" {
        currentPage = nil
    } else {
        tokens := strings.Split(line, ":")
        if len(tokens) == 2 {
            currentPage[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]
        }
    }
}
f, err := os.Create("strangecountess.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error :", err)
    return
}
defer f.Close()
bout, _ := json.Marshal(myBigThing)
f.Write(bout)
}
```

I am open to changing languages for this specific task if there is some awesome library out there that does this, I'm all ears. However staying in go is preferred :).

Comment: How do you identify a paragraph?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown this is in go, I didn't wan't to specify because I am any that will get the job done :)

Comment: @HotLicks by two 'enters' so something like '/n/n' but this parser only checks single characters

Comment: If the line length is greater than zero (not counting `\n`) then accumulate the line (with `\n`) in a temporary line buffer, appending to any previous such lines.  If the line length is zero, add the temp buffer to myBigThing and clear it for the next batch.  Do the same at the end.

Comment: (How you treat more than two `\n` in a row is up to you.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other tools, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) can probably do what you need.

Suppose the file `data` contains

```
When in the course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.
We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness. That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed.
```

The command

```
$ jq -MR '.' data
```

generates a sequence of strings, one per input line:

```
"When in the course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation."
"We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness. That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed."
```

The command

```
$ jq -MR -n '[inputs]' data
```

will collect the lines into an array:

```
[
  "When in the course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.",
  "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness. That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed."
]
```

Once you have a JSON object it's easy to add more processing.  e.g. this filter

```
$ jq -MR -n '[inputs] | map("\(.[:30])... \(length) characters")' data
```

summarizes each line:

```
[
  "When in the course of human ev... 404 characters",
  "We hold these truths to be sel... 337 characters"
]
```

and this command

```
$ jq -MR -n 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; .["\(.|length)"]=$i)' data
```

collects the lines into an object

```
{
  "0": "When in the course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.",
  "1": "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness. That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed."
}
```

There is an online version at https://jqplay.org/ as well.